# How to divide page in LaTex

Tags: latex

I want to divide my page into 2, and my texts will fill the left side, then automatically go to the right side. It should look like articles in books or newspapers

The solutions that I have found so far on Internet is to make a table or use minipage. But, then I have to cut the texts and put them in each part by myself.

I just want to write the whole document, then it automatically divides all the pages and fills the texts left and right. Is it possible in LaTex?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are thinking about a two-column document. LaTeX provides this by default via a `two-column` document class option:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

The above choice creates a document-wide setting. If you want more control over where you want multiple columns of text in your document, the [`multicol` package](//ctan.org/pkg/multicol)'s `multicols` environment is your friend:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\lipsum[1]

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[2-8]
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[9-10]

\end{document}
```